# После проверки месяца семестра выдало на else

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Python 3.10.4

После проверки истинна семестра (1-2) и выдало null *(на всякий случай указал else если что-то не так)*

````py
import time

TNamed_tuple = time.localtime()
TMon = int(time.strftime("%m", TNamed_tuple)) # int = 5, str = '05'

if (9 > TMon > 12) == True:
    TSemestr = 'Первая'
elif (1 > TMon > 8) == True:
    TSemestr = 'Вторая'
else:
    TSemestr = 'null'

print(f'\n>> {TMon} - {TSemestr}') # >> 5 - null
# Должно быть так: >> 5 - Вторая```
````

Comment: Никакое число не может быть одновременно меньше 9 и больше 12, и то же самое с 1 и 8. Направления условий поменяйте. Ну и условия у вас не включают границы.

Comment: значит должно отдельно проверять число? например, на and

Comment: Просто поменяйте направление условий (`>` на `<`), замените строгие условия на нестрогие (`<` на `<=`). Проверять на равенство True не нужно.

Comment: Теперь понял как это работает условия, я всегда писал на `>`, но иногда юзал на `<` и `<=`... Придётся привыкать. Спасибо

Comment: Заголовок вопроса переформулируйте, сейчас не очень понятно звучит то, что там написано в конце.

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Изменено направление условия ">" на "<=", а также убрано лишняя проверка True и выдало нужные результаты:

```py
if (9 <= TMon <= 12):
    TSemestr = 'Первая'
elif (1 <= TMon <= 8):
    TSemestr = 'Вторая'
else:
    TSemestr = 'null'
```